# Calculating the Chi Squared from combinations of subgroups

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, computational-statistics

Let's say I can calculate the chi squared p-value of different categorical variables and summarise them into a table like so:

Initial Data:

```
                    days_spent
person      city
   1       London          111
   1   Birmingham          133
   1   Manchester          100
   2       London          133
   2   Birmingham           50
   2   Manchester          113
   3       London          111
   3   Birmingham          200
   3   Manchester          200
   4       London          300
```

Chi squared of the categorical variables:

```
                     chisquare
       city
     London         3.5912478802624086e-35
 Manchester         3.4168808803447015e-12
 Birmingham         6.2738707647980595e-21
```

Using degrees of freedom equal one minus the number of categories.

However, let's say I also want to calculate 'combinations of categories'. E.g. the chi squared of London & Manchester or Birmingham & Manchester. How would I, from the chi squared of the categorical variables, determine the p-value when they are combined? Is it a lossy transformation?

I can also pass through the count of the variables and other metrics from the original dataset if that helps?

I'm using this for something called [CHAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHAID) in case you are wondering.

Comment: What hypothesis are you testing with the above chi-square test?  Equality of fraction of time spent?  What do you mean "degrees of freedom equal one minus the number of categories"?  That would give negative numbers.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. So for city, there would be 2 degrees of freedom because there are 3 different cities I'll fix the typo. Secondly i just want to determine if what I'm trying to do is possible. It's from a theoretical point of view. I'm testing whether I have to go back to the raw data to calculate the p-value of the chisquare for combinations of cities or I can get those values from the initially aggregated data.